# PHP, Laravel join results of two queries and display it selectively in a html/blade table

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, laravel

I'm trying to combine/join two (preferably more) queries' results. And then selectively display it in my blade view, in a table, selecting only a few columns/properties. I'm trying to do it in Laravel, eloquent/querybuilder (I could do it in pure sql, but that's not the point of course) as it will be using multible databases and tables, possibly on multiple servers.
To the point: here's a bit of the code:

```
$query1 = Documents::join('warehouses', 'analyticsData.documents.warehouse', '=', 'analyticsData.warehouses.id')
        ->selectRaw(
            ' analyticsData.warehouses.name name,
        analyticsData.documents.warehouse number,
        SUM(analyticsData.documents.value) takings1'
        )
        ->whereIn('analyticsData.documents.type', [1, 4, 5])
        ->whereDate('date', '>=', '2016-09-05')
        ->whereDate('date', '<=', '2016-09-10')
        ->limit('5000')
        ->groupBy('name1')
        ->get();

    $query2 = Documents::join('warehouses', 'analyticsData.documents.warehouse', '=', 'analyticsData.warehouses.id')
        ->selectRaw(
            ' analyticsData.warehouses.name name,
        analyticsData.documents.warehouse number,
        SUM(analyticsData.documents.value) takings2')

        ->whereIn('analyticsData.documents.type', [1, 4, 5])
        ->whereDate('date', '>=', '2017-09-04')
        ->whereDate('date', '<=', '2017-09-09')
        ->limit('5000')
        ->groupBy('name1')
        ->get();
```

Then, with a foreach loop I want to display selected columns of the results on screen in a table, in blade.
I've been at it for a few days actually and tried among other things merging the results as arrays with array_merge, but it just appends one array at the end of the other. I need the equivalent of a '(right)join' in SQL. The columns 'name' and 'number' are the same.
Frankly none of the collection or arrays methods and their combinations seem to work.
I'll be tremendously grateful for any help.

PS. Also, if anyone happens to know how I cant get a sum of values from a column in a specific query, not using selectRaw, I'd be ecstatic.

Comment: are you able to combine it? what is the issue?

Comment: I cannot use 'combine', because the arrays (if I convert them into arrays) are uneven. I need exactly an equivalent of an sql 'join'. Or else a way to display it properly - one column next to the other.

Comment: To be clear: array_combine(): Both parameters should have an equal number of elements

Answer (score 0):

i did multiple joins with query builder.

here is my code:

```
$result = DB::table('sub_categories')->join('categories', 'sub_categories.category_id', '=', 'categories.id')
        ->join('main_categories', 'main_categories.id', '=', 'categories.main_category_id')
        ->where([['main_categories.text', '=', $mainCategory], ['categories.text', '=', $category], ['sub_categories.text', '=', $subCategory]])
        ->select('sub_categories.id as subject_id')->get();
```

and this one maybe be helpful:

```
$result = DB::table('users')->where([['users.user_id', $userId], ['ad_is_verified', true]])
        ->join('ads', 'ads.user_id', '=', 'users.user_id')
        ->where('ads.ad_id', '=', $addId)->get();
```

Comment: Thanks, but the thing is, my ultimate goal is to join a couple of pairs of tables and then to join those joins (I hope this is pretty much clear). Multiple joins of one table with a couple of other tables are not what I'm looking for. I need to find a way to join the result sets of a couple of queries. Or else find a way to diplay selectively, in a table, the results of merged arrays. In fact, if I could perform a 'combine' on uneven/unequal arrays, I think it would solve it. But apparently a 'combine' cannot be performed with arrays that have different numbers of elements.

Comment: instead of join you should use union for your case.

Comment: It's not exactly the solution I had in mind, and I'm not sure if in this case 'union' should work. Nevertheless I can't seem to apply union to my code, but Expected \Closure|\Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder, got \App\ModelsAnalyticsData\Documents[]|\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection|\Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder[]|\Illuminate\Support\Collection. 
Invocation parameter types are not compatible with declared.

Comment: Scratch the last comment - I managed to do a 'union' on collections with the results after I completed the queries. However - I will have to look closer if the solution is what I'm looking for. Because initially I didn't think so.

Comment: I actually need all the data from the queries. Union of course replaces some data in a set with data from another. In short - on of the sets contains the name of a shop and  the earnings from one period and the other set contains the name of a shop and the earnings from another period. Now - in one of the sets a shop could have earnings, and in the other the same shop's earnings could be equal to null. I need data from both periods.